# Nodejs/Express: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I switched my nodejs template engine over to ejs (from jade). When I run my app.js with my ejs template, I receive a series of "Failed to lookup view 'error' in views" logs.

Some of which include:

```
GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 500 12.588 ms - 1390
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
...
GET /css/clean-blog.min.css
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
...
GET /js/bootstrap.min.js
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
...
GET /js/jquery.js
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
```

Thing is, many of these dependencies are included in the template itself (included  via script tags). What is the proper place to get these to work in express? It seems like express ultimately should not be looking for these in the `views` folder (since they aren't views).

Comment: How did you setup EJS? Did you `app.set("view engine" ...`?

Comment: Have you added `app.use(express.static('public'));` ?

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes I have used `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`
@Molda I am using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure your Express App has this setup, for the current layout it sounds like you have.

```
// Require static assets from public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set 'views' directory for any views 
// being rendered res.render()
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Set view engine as EJS
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

It is pretty normal for views that are getting rendered by `res.render()` to be placed in a 'Views' directory at the top level of your app. The `express-generator` actually uses that view setup. You can change that by modifying the below line

```
// replace with the directory path below ./
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Comment: I see. So why does express provide a public folder if it looks for these things in 'views'? These would be considered public, wouldn't they? Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @ApathyBear The public folder is for static assets or for use with other front-end frameworks like Angular or React. However, you don't even need to use the public folder, you can make it whatever you like and you can declare multiple directories static. The primary motivation probably is that these views need to have the data injected and multiple templates brought together in some cases.

Comment: I had to change the last line: app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); in order to work

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Express doesn't find your files, so your poor little server want to return an error, but your error file is missing in `views` directory.

In views directory, you have just to create a file called error.jade.

Then you have to search where Express searches your files yet.

Comment: This actually fixed for me, created a views/error.pug file and then express threw the actual error.

Comment: Cool. I didn't check, but I think message comes from Express, so error, and problem, is the same for any view engine, Pug/Jade, Ejs and so on.

Comment: @Plaute, your solution gives me 500 Server Error

Comment: A file cannot result in a 500 answer code, you have another problem.
Look at your server log file, these is always a response to your problems.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my issue by using below code.

```
    // Require static assets from public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// Set view engine as EJS
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// Set 'views' directory for any views 
// being rendered res.render()
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, ''));
app.use('/form', express.static(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```

Comment: Please explain *how* this code solves the issue and how it's different from the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

its worked foe me , in my case:

i need to remove ./views/ from  ./views/payment.pug

```
res.render('payment.pug', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
```

this is incorrect:

```
res.render('./views/payment.pug', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
              ^^^^^^
```

should remove ^^^^^^^^^ and just like first sample

Comment: I think just `'payment'` will also work. No .pug ext is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Check file extension
In my case, i use .js instead of .ejs

Answer (score -1):

Remove app.use(expresslayouts). The express-ejs-layouts module is used to avoid duplication of code when there are multiple html pages. In the above code there is only one html page, so express-ejs-layouts is not required.

Once you have started using layouts in your views folder then you can use it. It won't create any problem then else in the starting you can simply avoid using expresslayouts

Answer (score -2):

I fixed mine by adding this:

app.set('views', './src/views');

Answer (score -2):

I had my file with extension .js and I renamed it to .ejs in my view directory which I have set it up in ./src/pages

Comment: That's the same answer that @user11436097 posted. If you feel yours adds something that wasn't there, please elaborate.