# I have a server error from using ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have reviewed this question but I could not solve the problem
[Nodejs/Express: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604730/nodejs-express-error-failed-to-lookup-view-error-in-views-directory)

I have these server setup

```js
const express = require('express');
    var jquery = require('jquery');
    var admin = require("firebase");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')



const app = express();

 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');




app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
 
    res.render('login');
})


when I run the server this is the error I get 

>>Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory 


what am I doing wrongly?
```

Comment: add this `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` after setting ejs. You will need also to require `path` module `const path = require('path');`

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer?