# See Node-js value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to see a Node-js value in a html file. I used an engine called `pug`.

app.js:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('views','views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/', function(q,r){
    r.render('index', { dataFromServer: 'Alireza'});
});
app.listen(8081,err => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8081!');
});
```

index.pug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>
    var data = <%= dataFromServer %>
    alert(data)
  </script>
</html>
```

My `app.js` is in the following path:

`E:\Engine\app.js`

`index.pug` is in:

`E:\Engine\views`

And modules are in:

`E:\Engine\node_modules`

But the following error occurrs whenever i request the related port:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"
    at Function.render (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at E:\Engine\app.js:10:4
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Engine\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

This problem repeats whenever i change the engine. For example, i used `ejs` too. I altered path of `views` file many times but that error repeated again with my new paths. Please help a beginner man.

Answer (score 1):

That error seems to indicate that it is trying to find `index.pug` in some directory named `views`

Are you trying to hit `localhost:8081/index` or just `localhost:8081`? I think you just want to hit `/` (localhost:8081) to get `index.pug` in this case.

Also, instead of `app.set('views', 'views);`, you probably want `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

Comment: I tried all suggested ways but that same result occurred.

Comment: Sorry, that's frustrating. Looking at the backtrace, it looks like you are hitting line 10 of App.js which seems correct. Can you try hitting `localhost:8081/views/index.pug` ?

Comment: I found the problem. I work in Windows 10 and whenever i make an index.pug file with Notepad, Windows considers an index.pug.txt file. Because of that `Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"` occurrs. A .pug file is searched but a .txt file approached.

Comment: Oh that’s pretty subtle, well done. You may want to google how to change that default on notepad or try using another editor or it might happen again soon. Lots of people using windows really like VScode.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a duplicate for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604730/nodejs-express-error-failed-to-lookup-view-error-in-views-directory)?
Try using:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```