# "Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "E:\tozip\views" "

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete the item but it gives above error message. I have rewrited my code to solve the involvement of views directory.but it does not helps.

```
    router.delete('/:id', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
        const id  = req.params.id;
        await Book.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        res.send('deleted')
    }));
```

Comment: can any one share the reason for this type of error i have already checked  the  answers listed in ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604730/nodejs-express-error-failed-to-lookup-view-error-in-views-directory

Comment: Update !!!  i copied the code and i redone with small changes now it workd perfectly fine but i get's this error in my git bash shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it was my fault i forgot setup an error page for my app